# Registering exception listener in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, event-handling

I'm trying to register a listener for exceptions but it never gets called, here is my code:

app.yml:

```
services:
    kernel.listener.exception_listener:
        class: Appointmed\ApiBundle\EventListener\AppointmedExceptionEventListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

Acme/ApiBundle/EventListener/AcmeExceptionEventListener.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: danielrodriguez
 * Date: 28/02/14
 * Time: 19:14
 */

namespace Acme\ApiBundle\EventListener;

use JMS\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

class AcmeExceptionEventListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // You get the exception object from the received event
        $exception = $event->getException();
        $status = new Status($exception->getCode(), $exception->getMessage());

        // Customize your response object to display the exception details
        $response = new Response();
        $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
        $response->setContent($serializer->serialize(array("status" => $status), 'json'));
        $response->sendHeaders(array("ContentType" => "application/json"));

        // HttpExceptionInterface is a special type of exception that
        // holds status code and header details
        if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
            $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
            $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
        } else {
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        // Send the modified response object to the event
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Whenever I throw an exception in my controller, it doesn't go through the listener, don't know what's going on anymore.

One thing I could realize is that if I deliberately change the class in config.yml to something that don't exists, everything works the same. e.g.

```
services:
    kernel.listener.exception_listener:
        class: Appointmed\ApiBundle\EventListener\asdf
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `app\config.yml` includes an `imports` element `- { resource: services.yml }`, and that `services.yml` includes your service?

Comment: services are typically loaded via a dependency injection extension

Comment: namespace is not matched with service.yml and you must use symfony 2.4 to use Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Answer (score 1):

In your service definition,you have given the class name as 'AppointmedExceptionEventListener'.

But that class you have written is AcmeExceptionEventListener in the namespace 
Acme\ApiBundle\EventListener. If you fix this, you it should work as expected.